# Getting last value from multidimensional array outside foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I'm updating a database table and I receive a array from the input because there are multiple values (id[] , price[] , product[] , description[] and so on) but I want to get the LAST value of price[] outside foreach loop
I use this foreach loop that works to update the MAIN db table

```php
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $id) {
    $array1 = $_POST['product'][$key];
    $array2 = $_POST['priceunit'][$key];
    $array3 = $_POST['quantity'][$key];
    $array4 = $_POST['sum'][$key];
    $array5 = $_POST['totalprice'][$key];
    $query = $link -> prepare("UPDATE table SET product = ?, priceunit = ?, quantity = ?, sum = ?, totalprice = ? WHERE id = ?");
    $query -> bind_param('sddddi',$array1,$array2,$array3,$array4,$array5,$id);
    $result = $query-> execute();
    $query -> close();
}
```

and now I want to get the LAST VALUE from $array5 so I can do this outside the loop

```php
$sql = $link -> prepare("UPDATE table2 SET price = ? WHERE id = ?;");
$sql -> bind_param("ds",

    $total,  <- array5 last value
    $_GET['id']);

$query = $sql -> execute();
$sql -> close();
```

this is the input

```
<tbody>
<?php
        $sql = $link -> prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id_proposta = ?;");
        $sql -> bind_param('s',
             $_GET['id']);
        $sql -> execute();
        $result = $sql -> get_result();
        for ($i = 0; $r = $result -> fetch_assoc(); $i++){ ?>
        <tr>                                
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" name="id[]">                               
            <td><textarea class="form-control" name="product[]" rows="3" id="textareaAutosize" data-plugin-textarea-autosize><?php echo $r['product']; ?></textarea></td>       
            <td><input type="text" class="priceunit" value="<?php echo $r['priceunit']; ?>" name="priceunit[]"></td>                                                                
            <td><input type="text" class="qtd" value="<?php echo $r['quantity']; ?>" name="quantity[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="sum" value="<?php echo $r['sum']; ?>" name="sum[]" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="totalprice" value="<?php echo $r['totalprice']; ?>" name="totalprice[]" readonly></td>                                                            
        </tr>
<?php } $sql -> close(); ?>
</tbody>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "LAST VALUE from $array5"? Note that `$array5` is not an array.

Comment: You can declare $array5 before foreach and set a value inside. After the loop, you can use end() function to get the last value from this array.

Comment: I will edit the question so I can show you the input give me a minute..

Comment: @PaulSpiegel done

Comment: Hmm.. still not clear. But I think you need `$total = end($_POST['totalprice']);`.

Comment: already answered , thanks by the way !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do this in the loop:

```
$array5 = $_POST['totalprice'][$key];
```

Then after the loop is finished, `$array5` will be the last `$_POST['totalprice']`.  So just use it:

```
$sql->bind_param("ds",    
    $array5,
    $_GET['id']);
```

Or even this if you don't use all those temporary variables:

```
$sql->bind_param("ds",    
    $_POST['totalprice'][$key],
    $_GET['id']);
```

Comment: You're right - already deleted my comment. But my IDE would complain about "$array5 might not be declared".